# Generic fix to 'react/no-unstable-nested-components' eslint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

this is more of a JS lang question than react per-se (I think). So, here's a case: let's say I have a component defined on render, the easiest example I could think of is a `FlatList` item separator, so let's define it:

```
  const data = ['el0', 'el1', 'el2'];
  const renderItem = (el: string) => <Text>{el}</Text>;

  const Component = () => (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
        <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red' }} />
      )}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  );
```

Now, this is an easy fix, as we don't need to pass any props to it. But what if we did?

```
  const data = ['el0', 'el1', 'el2'];
  const renderItem = (el: string) => <Text>{el}</Text>;

  const Component = () => (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={({ width }: { width: number }) => (
        <View style={{ borderWidth: width, borderColor: 'red' }} />
      )}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  );
```

Now, I cannot just extract it to a component, let's say `Divider` and use `ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}` because I need the prop passed. So I came up with a solution, to use a generic function:

```
const getStableComponent =
  <T extends {}>(props: T) =>
  (Component: React.FC<T>) => {
    return () => <Component {...props} />;
  };
```

And the usage you can probably figure out - use it in place of the 'unstable' component, and pass it as an argument, while solving the props issue, like so:

```
ItemSeparatorComponent={getStableComponent({ width })(Divider)}
```

Now, my main question is - is it actually a solution? Am I passing the same reference (as that is how I understand it should work)? Is it possible to use a similar solution? Is it just silencing ESLint? And lastly, how would I test similar solutions in the future?

I tried moving it outside the component, like suggested in other SO questions and GH issues, but it's more time consuming (defining types for props always, here I have them handy already) and I wanted to know if the solution I provided is actually working, or just silencing errors.